# Azure Functions NodeJS: Https Request not working when using Azure Visual Studio Code Extension

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

I am working with Azure Functions in NodeJS. I first wrote the function having azure funct locally on my laptop. The code worked fine and did everything I wanted. Now, I added the code to a new azure function in my Azure Visual Studio Code Extention - the exact same code. BUT now it does not work anymore. I don't get an error or something, the https request is just not started.

Here is my code:

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const storage = require('azure-storage');
const STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME = 'SOMETHING';
const ACCOUNT_ACCESS_KEY = 'SOMETHING';

const blobService = storage.createBlobService(STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME, ACCOUNT_ACCESS_KEY);

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
    let _browser;
    let _page;


    https.get(SOMEURL", (resp) => {
        let data = '';

        // A chunk of data has been recieved.
        resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
            data += chunk;
        });

        // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
        resp.on('end', async () => {
            context.log('here');
        });

    }).on("error", (err) => {
        console.log("Error: " + err.message);
    });

};
```

It never prints the "here" which should be done after the https request ends. (The first context.log is however printed in both cases)

So my question is, what am I doing wrong? Can I not use https request inside azure functions when using the visual studio code extension?

Edit:

anyone who needs the async, here is a link explained how to do it with util.promisify: https://gist.github.com/krnlde/797e5e0a6f12cc9bd563123756fc101f

Comment: You shouldn't be mixing async and callbacks, your function execution is returning before your callback gets called. If you remove the `async` from the function definition and add a `context.done` call after your `context.log('here')` you should see the desired result. Otherwise you can change your code to be awaitable

Comment: This helps! Thanks. Could you additionally tell me how I would make it awaitable? Because I think i would need that

Comment: You can use another library like `axios` or see about wrapping callback based functions with `util.promisify` that will allow you to `await` on the wrapped function calls. Any function that returns a promise is `awaitable`. In azure functions you need to choose which style to use as it changes how you'll be handling function completion. For more information you should check the azure functions website:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've kept your code callback based.
I removed the `async` moniker from the definition and added a call to `context.done` (this signals the functions host when your function has ended) in your `resp.end` handler

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const storage = require('azure-storage');
const STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME = 'SOMETHING';
const ACCOUNT_ACCESS_KEY = 'SOMETHING';

const blobService = storage.createBlobService(STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME, ACCOUNT_ACCESS_KEY);

module.exports = function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
    let _browser;
    let _page;


    https.get(SOMEURL", (resp) => {
        let data = '';

        // A chunk of data has been recieved.
        resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
            data += chunk;
        });

        // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
        resp.on('end', async () => {
            context.log('here');
            context.done();
        });

    }).on("error", (err) => {
        console.log("Error: " + err.message);
    });

};
```

Another option would be to keep the function as `async` but you'd need to replace the callbacks with `promise` based calls. In some scenarios this can be achieved by wrapping them using [util.promisify](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) and then calling them with the `await` keyword

Comment: would that mean that I have to wrap the https.get calls inside the util.promisify? Then I could keep the async at the beginning?

Comment: Something like this: https://gist.github.com/krnlde/797e5e0a6f12cc9bd563123756fc101f should do the trick if you want to go the `async` way. See more info on util.promisify here: https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_custom_promisified_functions